# How would you model this database relationship?

Tags: python, database, django, database-design

I'm modeling a database relationship in django, and I'd like to have other opinions. The relationship is kind of a two-to-many relationship. For example, a patient can have two physicians: an attending and a primary. A physician obviously has many patients.

The application does need to know which one is which; further, there are cases where an attending physician of one patient can be the primary of another. Lastly, both attending and primary are often the same.

At first, I was thinking two foreign keys from the patient table into the physician table. However, I think django disallows this. Additionally, on second thought, this is really a many(two)-to-many relationship.

Therefore, how can I model this relationship with django while maintaining the physician type as it pertains to a patient? Perhaps I will need to store the physician type on the many-to-many association table?

Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
class Patient(models.Model):
    primary_physician = models.ForeignKey('Physician', related_name='primary_patients')
    attending_physicial = models.ForeignKey('Physician', related_name='attending_patients')
```

This allows you to have two foreign keys to the same model; the `Physician` model will also have fields called `primary_patients` and `attending_patients`.

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting. I'm glad that I asked. django did suggest using related_name in error.

Comment: Yes -- it's because, in absence of "related_name", Physician would acquire a "patient_set" reverse relation. But this causes an error because both fields would try to create a "patient_set" reverse relation. If you have a foreign key to the same model, you have to specify "related_name" to avoid this issue.

Comment: This will lead to duplicates while retrieving a physician's patient list. The application will need to take the union.

Comment: Do you see that as a downside to this approach?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. I think's is probably the _best_ way, using Django's ORM layer. You can always turn the results into a set and take the union; or if performance is an issue, you can always write custom SQL queries, I suppose.

Comment: Better yet, you could probably create a custom manager for the Physician model (call it "patients") with a method like "unique" that would return both types of patients, without duplicates. You could even use custom SQL in the manager, if need be. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#topics-db-managers

Comment: Just say Patient.objects.filter(Q(primary_physician=a_physician) | Q(attending_physicial=a_physician)).  I think this model is the *best* way, even from a raw schema perspective; it models the relationship exactly and naturally.  ("Q" is new to 1.1, which isn't out yet, but I wouldn't go near 1.0; it's missing too much stuff.  I've found Django trunk to be very stable, at least currently.)

Comment: Glenn, it's funny you mention this because they've just released 1.1rc tonight! Thanks for the advice since I'm new to django and python.

I agree with you that mipadi offers the best solution.

Comment: @Glenn: Django has Q-objects since at least version 0.96 (http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/db-api/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). You're probably thinking of F-objects, which are new in Django 1.1 (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a many-to-many join table.  Use application logic to prevent more than two physicians per patient.

```
Physician
    Physician_ID
    ...

Patient
    Patient_ID
    ...

Physician_Patient
    Physician_ID int not null
    Patient_ID int not null
    Type ENUM ('Primary', 'Attending')
    PRIMARY KEY (Physician_ID, Patient_ID)
    KEY (Patient_ID)
```

Comment: You may be able to even put a database-level constraint in, too.  Depending upon your DBMS.

Comment: Django's ORM layer doesn't have a model that represents a join table. Join tables are created automatically, and extra columns can't be added to them. You can create a model with ForeignKey fields that can conceptually represent a join table, and add extra fields to that, but it would be a bit unwieldy in the face of other solutions.

Comment: Sure it does.  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships I don't see any reason to use an M2M relationship here, though.  A regular foreign key is just fine.

Comment: As I said: "You can create a model with ForeignKey fields that can conceptually represent a join table, and add extra fields to that, but it would be a bit unwieldy in the face of other solutions." :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your conclusion. I would store the physician type in the many-to-many linking table.